# rosmake failed for g2o

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, g2o

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

i want to install rgbdslam package. so i used the svn co link. in that i followed the readme file and i tried to install g2o. when i gave rosmake i got following error:

root@mutu-Vostro-3550:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/g2o# rosmake --rosdep-install
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['g2o']
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['g2o']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/mutu/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120416-145054
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['g2o'] to:
['g2o']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Failed to find rosdep suitesparse for package g2o on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed

if rosmake fails the readme file has the next step.i did it, but i got the following:

root@mutu-Vostro-3550:/opt/ros/electric/stacks/g2o# sudo apt-get install libsuitesparse-dev libcsparse2.2.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libcsparse2.2.3 is already the newest version.
libsuitesparse-dev is already the newest version.

what to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31870/rosmake-failed-for-g2o/) by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-04-17**:
You should be able to continue compiling g2o anyway, shouldn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i removed the source files and installed g2o from ubuntu software centre

---

Originally posted by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) with karma: 36 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-04-20**:
Are you using fuerte?

**Comment by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on 2012-04-20**:
no i'm using electric. actually when installing rgbdslam i had to download svn g2o again and install for the package. this time didn't get error, it built without failures.